# AndroidPlot and RectRegion

Tags: java, android, androidplot

I am using Androidplot (v0.5.0) and I want segments of my plotted series to be different colours.
I think I need to use RectRegion but the region never shows.

```
XYSeries series = new SimpleXYSeries(timestamps, item.getValues(), "");  
LineAndPointFormatter seriesFmt = new LineAndPointFormatter(
        Color.rgb(0, 200, 0),
        Color.rgb(0, 100, 0),
        Color.rgb(150, 190, 150));

XYRegionFormatter regionFmter = new XYRegionFormatter(Color.RED);
RectRegion region = new RectRegion(0, 10, 0, 10);
seriesFmt.addRegion(region, regionFmter);
```

I cant find the doco anymore for this but I can find old images from the old tutorials of what I was trying to achieve.
http://androidplot.com/w/images/thumb/1/12/RectRegions_final.jpg/398px-RectRegions_final.jpg[image]

Comment: What are the values returned by item.getValues()?

Comment: I was wondering if the values all fall outside the boundaries of the region defined?  Any chance you can post a pic of what is currently being drawn in your implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a link to the full source code that generated the graphic you posted - hopefully that provides answers you are looking for :)

https://androidplot.jira.com/source/browse/ANDROIDPLOT/trunk/Examples/DemoApp/src/com/androidplot/demos/XYRegionExampleActivity.java?hb=true